# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate Oracle SQL, how to escape single quote in named query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have the following code where I can't seem to figure out how to escape the single quotes around my named parameter. In the resulting query, I need to have single quotes on either side of it:

```
        public List<Vehicle> findByApplicationId(String applicationId) {
            // example application id is a string like 12345
            MapSqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            sqlParameterSource.addValue("applicationId", applicationId);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("SELECT make, model");
            stringBuilder.append(" FROM vehicle");
            stringBuilder.append(" WHERE model IN (SELECT id FROM auto WHERE model_app IN (");
            stringBuilder.append(":applicationId");
            stringBuilder.append("))");
           // in the resulting query the applicationId must appear 
           // as '12345', meaning with single quotes around it

            return jdbcTemplate.query(stringBuilder.toString(), sqlParameterSource,
                    // lambda used as row mapper
                    (resultSet, rowNumber) -> {...
    ...
```

I've tried to put double single quotes around the name parameter as in `stringBuilder.append("'':applicationId''");`, that didn't work. I tried single single quotes and many other such combinations of single and double quotes based on other answers I've seen on SO. Can't seem to get it.

Comment: You do not need single quotes if you are binding the value as a string.

Comment: @AlexPoole I did try without quotes. Although the named parameter resolves when looking at the resulting query via debug logs, I still don't get data whereas in the SQL client putting the exact same query in pulls data. So I figures something isn't getting sent correctly in the query. Would you please show what you mean by a small example? I even tried to make the named parameter and integer with different combinations of quoting. Some times it resolves but with the wrong number of quotes, other times the query is considered bad SQL grammar.

Comment: Single quotes aren't the answer though. You'd be saerching for the literal string value `':applicationId'`, it wouldn't be treated as a bind variable, and the actual value 12345 wouldn't be used. Did you perhaps just insert the data you're looking for in the SQL client that can see it - and haven't committed? Just a thought. Otherwise what is the column data type?

Comment: @AlexPoole Agreed, I realized that the hard way, currently, as I have the code above, the resulting query in the debug logs (the end of it) looks like `...IN (?))]` but that doesn't fetch any data whereas a literal text substitution of the name parameter with it's value will.

Comment: Literal substitution works from Java (with escaped single quotes), not just from your SQL client!? How about if you concatenate in the parm? Have you checked the actual value doesn't have trailing spaces say, or some other data type issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem wasn't single quotes at all as suggest by Alex Poole (thank you Alex). It was that my Java string needed to be cast to the Oracle type CHAR(17). After I did that no quotes, single or double, were necessary and my named parameters resolved correctly and the query worked.